# From character to chr()

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string and I want to convert each character to it's appropriate ASCII character.

```
Sub IterateCharactersObject()
    Dim ch As Characters, n As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        For n = 1 To .Characters.Count
            Set ch = .Characters(n, 1)

            Debug.Print ch.Text & ", " & Asc(ch) '<-- what should go in place of Asc(ch)?

        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

Not sure what function I am looking for and can't seem to find.

If my string started with "A big...." then

- When `n= 1` output is `A, 65`
- When `n= 2` output is `, 32`

I am essentially looking for the inverse of `Chr()` function in VBA

Comment: stoops. the answer is `Asc(ch.text)`. Without the `.text` it spits out invalid results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String` and `Mid`

```
Sub IterateCharactersObject()
    Dim ch As String, n As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        For n = 1 To .Characters.Count
            ch = Mid(.Value, n, 1)

            Debug.Print ch & ", " & Asc(ch) '<-- what should go in place of Asc(ch)?

        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Would have avoided the headache of the `ch.text` for sure. Thank you as always for the lessons